# What's the difference between overflow: auto and overflow: clip?

Tags: css

Simple question, one element has overflow:auto and another element has overflow:clip.
What is the difference?

```css
.some-div{
   overflow: auto;
}

.another-div{
   overflow: clip;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow/#overflow-properties)

> If the computed value of overflow on a block box is neither visible nor clip nor a combination thereof, it establishes an **independent formatting context** for its contents.

The creation of formatting context is the main difference

Here is a demo

```css
.box {
  border:2px solid;
  margin:10px;
}
.box div {
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="overflow:auto">
  <div></div> text
</div>

<div class="box" style="overflow:clip">
  <div></div> text
</div>
```

Notice how in the second case, the div remain collapsed because there is no creating of a block formatting context to contain the float element